# How to replot or refresh primefaces charts on window resize?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces charts and whenever i resize the window the x-axis moves a bit higher and the chart changes. This is how the chart looks before resizing

[image]

This is how the it looks when i resize the window:

[image]

My Question is how to replot or refresh it whenever the window resizes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This Is Built in in recent versions of primefaces

Comment: @Kukeltje i am using the latest version but it doesn't resize according to screen size.

Comment: Showcase of reponsive charts does

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes i saw that and add the responsive attribute as well but it's not resizing.

Comment: Then create a [mcve]. Always a good thing to do